# SQL - Get data for yesterday and day before

Tags: sql

I am running this query:

```
select member, customerinfo.customerid -- ...other irrelevant columns...
from customerinfo, addressinfo
    where customerinfo.customerid = addressinfo.customerid
    and MEMBER = (Date(GetDate()-1))
    and addressinfo.addresstype = 's'
```

I it is obviously giving me data if Member = yesterday.

My question is, how do I structure the query to give me data if Member = the last 2 days (yesterday and the day before)?

Comment: Warning! Old-style JOIN detected. Please use INNER JOIN syntax.

Comment: How intuitive is it that `MEMBER` is a datetime column? Also, how is this query giving you anything? I get `Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 16 / 'DATE' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

Comment: And finally: please always tag with what RDBMS you're using, so you don't waste people's time. `sql` is way too general a tag - we write SQL in 20+ different dialects.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
MEMBER BETWEEN (GETDATE() -2) AND (GETDATE() -1)
```

In SQL Server you can also try:

```
MEMBER BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -2, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: This seemed to work:  MEMBER BETWEEN(Date(GetDate()-2)) AND (Date(GetDate()-1))

Comment: What version of SQL Server are all you people using where `DATE()` is a built-in function? I'm so utterly confused.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, in the start the question wasn't tagged with SQL SERVER. It was later added after the EDIT, I don't think its correct.

Comment: @Habib I didn't notice that someone had added the sql-server tag. So how do we know what RDBMS the OP is using?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I can only guess that is MySQL. I haven't used the `DATE` function in my code, only after pointing out by the OP that it works, I edited to code for future reference

Comment: MySQL does not have `GETDATE()` though.

Answer (score 1):

Change your query in:

```
SELECT member, customerinfo.customerid, ContactName, Address1,
Address2, City, State, ZIP, Country from customerinfo, addressinfo
WHERE customerinfo.customerid = addressinfo.customerid
and MEMBER >= (Date(GetDate()-2)) AND MEMBER <= (Date(GetDate()-1))
and addressinfo.addresstype = 's'
```